# How to get the commit hash ID for a file?

Tags: git

I used `git checkout commit_hash path/to/file` to rollback a file to an older version.

After that, I forgot the commit hash ID that I used to retrieve this file. I used `git status path/to/file`, it shows this file is modified even though I did nothing to this file (I think it compares to HEAD).

Is there any way to get commit hash ID of this retrieved file?

Comment: Just recall the checkout command, every shell does this for you.

Comment: Please don't use `#` to mean hash. No one will understand you unless you make it ridiculously clear that that's what you're doing. Even then it will be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
git log filename
```

It would show the file log starting from the latest. If you forget, you could use shell history command. Assuming it's not too old.

Comment: you could check the shell history command, it should still be there

Comment: Is there any git command to do this instead of checking shell history?

Answer (score 1):

Try the command `history | grep path/to/file`.

Since there might be many commits that hold the same version of `path/to/file`, the result would not be precise enough through git commands. Here's one of the tries.

```
git hash-object path/to/file
```

And you'll get a hash number($hash). It's the blob name of the very version of `path/to/file`.

```
for commit in $(git rev-list --all --reflog);do
    git ls-tree -r $commit -- path/to/file | if grep $hash;then echo $commit;fi
done
```

All the candidates will be printed and you'll have to identify the commit in your memory among them all. Maybe `then git log -1 $commit` would make it more recognisable than `then echo $commit`.